# Textblock collapsed using space

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a C# WPF project. I am using an `ObservableCollection<T>` in my `viewmodel` class.

I have a `ListView` in `xaml` file. There is `TextBlock` inside the `ListView` binding to the `ObservableCollection<T>`.

I want to collapse them by `DataTrigger`. The result is that those `TextBlock` is collapsed but still using space. I would like to ask how to fix it?

Here is the `ListView` I am using:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1"  ItemsSource="{Binding ServiceObjects}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ServiceName}">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCollapsed}" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFBF00" />
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with "Hidden" instead of "Collapsed"?

Comment: Yes, I have tried, that is not okay. I now find that this is caused by the grid, but how can I collapse the grid when elements inside the grid is collapsed ?

Comment: Can't you just move your style from textbox to the grid ?

Comment: Not sure how to bind my data to grid, seems need to use grid view? May be I should just remove the grid ?

Comment: I removed grid but still facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="LstBoxItemStyle">
   <Setter Property="MinHeight"
           Value="0" />
   <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
           Value="False" />
   <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCollapsed}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                       Value="True" />
          </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and

```
  <ListView Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ServiceObjects}"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LstBoxItemStyle}">
```

Or use filters https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-filter-data-in-a-view?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Thank you, I am new to csharp, I would like to ask where should I put that <Style> ? Is it under DataTemplate ?

Comment: You can add it to UserControl.Resources or Window.Resources depending on what you are using

Comment: i.e:
`
<UserControl>
<UserControl.Resouces>
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="LstBoxItemStyle">
...
</Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
...
</UserControl>
`

Comment: Thank you, I added <Window.Resources> that works.